# Visual Studio Professional 2017 - Recent tab - One project always shows up as opened Today

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a weird thing happening in my IDE. One project always shows up as being opened today in the `Recent` tab even though I have not modified anything and not opened the project. If I right click and select `Remove From List` the project is removed and added automatically after a few seconds. It only happens for this project and it have been doing it for quite some time. Every other project works as expected. Source control is git like most of my other projects and I'm not doing a pull or anything like that. Has anyone else experienced this?

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. Have no idea what is happening.

Comment: @GeorgeHandlin Still happening to me, really weird.

Comment: me too. Very odd indeed.

Comment: Same here, but sometimes I get 2 doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

In looking further it looks like they just released VS 2017 15.3 that fixes this error.  Downloading it now. (Appears to have fixed it once the bad entries are removed.)